# VBA Conditional Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I am struggling to figure out an elegant way to apply conditional formatting rules via VBA. I prefer VBA because a) the rules will apply to multiple worksheets, and b) it prevents the CF duplication problem when copying/pasting between worksheets.

I have a list of inventory items, all kept in different locations. I want to format based on location with the following formatting:

Font color (will change for each location); Top border (same color as font); Bottom border (same color as font)

Also, the range needs to be dynamic in that for each worksheet, it applies to the table on that sheet. I would like to apply the same code to each applicable worksheet, rather than needing to hard-code the table name for each worksheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

--UPDATE--
I tried to adapt J_V's code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112764/excel-conditional-formatting-macro) but receive a "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" on the Public Sub's `r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula`. I'm unsure if the last bit on borders is correct since the run-time stops the macro. I also still need to work in dynamic table references, but I'm working one issue at a time.

```
Sub ConditionalFormatting()

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Widget1").Range("Widget1_table[Location]")

myRange.FormatConditions.Delete

Call FormatRange(myRange, 10, "=$E5="Warehouse1")
Call FormatRange(myRange, 11, "=$E5="Warehouse2")
Call FormatRange(myRange, 13, "=$E5="Warehouse3")

End Sub

Public Sub FormatRange(r As Range, color As Integer, formula As String)
r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula
r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).Font.colorindex = color

With r.FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = color
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With r.FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = color
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
r.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd start by recording a macro that applies CF to one table. Then expand it by cycling through each sheet in the workbook and, if necessary, each listobject (Table) in those sheets.

Comment: It is a *seriously* bad idea to name your variables the same as the reserved words of collection properties. `Formula1:=formula` is unadvised but `.Color = color` is just plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jeeped, I will rename the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not actually within `Sub FormatRange` but in the way you are assigning the formula when calling it within `Sub ConditionalFormatting`. The formula contains a string so the quotes have to be doubled up like this.

```
Sub ConditionalFormatting()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Widget1").Range("Widget1_table[Location]")

    myRange.FormatConditions.Delete

    Call FormatRange(myRange, 10, "=$E5=""Warehouse1""")
    Call FormatRange(myRange, 11, "=$E5=""Warehouse2""")
    Call FormatRange(myRange, 13, "=$E5=""Warehouse3""")
End Sub
```

As to the second macro, when you add a new condition it goes to the bottom of the queue. If you look at the recorded output from creating a CF rule you will see that it typically contains the line,

```
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
```

This puts the CF rule at the top of the queue so that it can thereafter be referred to as `.FormatConditions(1)`. If you do not want it at the top of the queue then you have to refer to it as the *last* in the queue like this.

```
Public Sub FormatRange(r As Range, clr As Integer, frml As String)
    r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=frml
    r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).Font.ColorIndex = clr

    With r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).Borders(xlTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = clr
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = clr
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

I also changed your border `.Color` assignments to `.ColorIndex` as *10, 11* & *13* seem to be **ColorIndex** identifiers for *green, blue and *purple*. The vowels were removed from your variable names to avoid conflict with the names of collection properties.

Comment: Jeeped, thank you so much for the changes as they fix the Run-time error. Do you know how I can replace the "Warehouse#" reference in `"=$E5=""Warehouse1""")` with a named range reference or reference from another worksheet? I realize now that it would be optimal if I could reference `Admin$A$1`--where `Warehouse1` exists in a list--or the named range `Warehouse1` rather than hard-coding `Warehouse1` into the macro.

Comment: Only Excel 2010 and higher allow you the cell address of another worksheet when creating a CF rule based upon a formula. For Excel 2010 and higher this would be something like `Call FormatRange(myRange, 10, "=$E5='Admin'!$A$1)`. A named range is more versatile and the value can be sliced off with `INDEX` like `Call FormatRange(myRange, 10, "=$E5=INDEX(my_List, 1, 1)")`. A better method would be to have both the colorindex number and the text string in your named range like `Call FormatRange(myRange, INDEX(my_List, 1, 2), "=$E5=INDEX(my_List, 1, 1)")` Provide specifics if you are having trouble