# How to apply conditional formatting for only visible cells?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using Excel-2010, I have applied 3scale conditional formatting for Excel range A1:F100, on a Dropdown macro hide/unhide will be actioned, and hide/unhide is not sequential, for eg:- Rows 1,10,30,54,67,88 may only visible.

So for only these visible rows, the same conditional format should Work.

I have tried browsing to find it, but i couldn't get the required.

Help is much Appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to programmatically do it. Like changing the range where the formatting applies to. [See this to know about applying formatting to a range of cells programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500483/conditional-formatting-using-3-conditions-in-macro-vba/22501780#22501780)

Comment: If you could accept AVERAGE instead of MEDIAN (50%-PERCENTILE) for the Midpoint, then there is a possibility with SUBTOTAL formulas for Minimum, Midpoint and Maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, it should be something like this:

```
Sub ject()
    Dim rng As Range
    With Sheet1 '~~> change to your actual sheet
        .Range("A1:F100").FormatConditions.Delete
        Set rng = .Range("A1:F100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Range("A1").FormatConditions.AddColorScale 3
        With .Range("A1").FormatConditions(1)
            With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
                .Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
                .FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
            With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
                .Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
                .FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End With
            With .ColorScaleCriteria(3)
                .Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
                .FormatColor.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End With
            .ModifyAppliesToRange rng
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Everytime this routine is run or called, it re-applies formatting to visible ranges. 
It can be incorporated to an existing code or run separately. HTH.

Comment: :-) Great, Thanks L42, This become like ready code, Changed only color codes. Much Appreciated.

Comment: @expfresh np. glad it helped and hope helps more readers. I receive a lot of help myself in this site. I'm just giving back if I can.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility with SUBTOTAL formulas for Minimum, Midpoint and Maximum.

Minimum: Type = Formula, `=SUBTOTAL(105,$A$1:$F$100)`

Midpoint: Type = Formula, `=MEDIAN(IF((SUBTOTAL(103,INDIRECT("A"&ROW($1:$100)))>0)*($A$1:$F$100<>""),$A$1:$F$100))`

Maximum: Type = Formula, `=SUBTOTAL(104,$A$1:$F$100)`

If you could accept the average of the values instead the 50% percentile as the Midpoint, the formula for Midpoint would be simpler:

```
=SUBTOTAL(101,$A$1:$F$100)
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: In Excel 2010 you can use `AGGREGATE` function to ignore hidden rows, and which has an inbuilt option for `Median`, e.g. `=AGGREGATE(12,1,A1:F100)`