# Conditional Formatting (cell value equal to) applies to dynamic table

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, dynamic-tables

In Excel Conditional Formatting, I can use `Indirect("table1")` (structured referencing) in the *Rule* (on the left) but not in the *Applies to* (on the right) where Excel auto-corrects "table1" (relative reference range, structured referencing) to an absolute reference range.

Is there any workaround? Because I need to apply to a dynamic (expanding columns) table.

Comment: if you want VBA solution, then Create Dynamic range. Many ways for this, u can have lastrow and lastcolumn assigned to variable or you can select currentregion..etc., then follow the code in the this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660087/how-to-apply-conditional-formatting-for-only-visible-cells

Comment: An example will be this: https://app.box.com/s/e96khwqnipw5jcy7y4b1

Answer (score 0):

Where structured references are involved (a Table of the type to which "expanding columns" could be applied) the *Applies to* range may be set with a structured reference and even though this is automatically converted by Excel into a 'standard' range (with anchors) it does not restrict the application of Conditional Formatting to the range indicated when rows are added to the table because (despite the anchors) the Conditional Formatting range is automatically "expanded" as the Table columns are extended.