# Conditional formatting wit AND not working

Tags: excel, vba

I try to apply a conditional formatting to change the background color of cell if is 2 conditions return true. Individual condition are working but if i add the AND(), it's not working...

```
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=AND(A2="""", A2<>B2)"
    .FormatConditions(5).Interior.Color = vbBlack
    .FormatConditions(5).StopIfTrue = False
```

EDIT: don't ask me, A2 is empty and different than B2 ;)

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code? I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish with that `=AND(..)`

Comment: I found a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473622/conditional-formatting-using-and-function